# Why is `skorecard.WoeEncoder()` so slow and how can I make it faster?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using [`WoeEncoder()`](https://github.com/ing-bank/skorecard/blob/main/skorecard/preprocessing/_WoEEncoder.py) from the [`skorecard`](https://pypi.org/project/skorecard/) Python library to target-encode lots of features for predictive modelling, but it's incredibly slow for some reason.

Is there any way of modifying the code for `WoeEncoder()` to retain the **same functionality** but just make it run much faster? I need to use it in sklearn pipelines etc.

Reproducible example showing the huge speed differences:

```
from skorecard.preprocessing import WoeEncoder # pip install skorecard

import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# timing:
import time
from humanfriendly import format_timespan

def tic():
    global st
    st = time.time()
    
def toc():
    et = time.time()
    time_elapsed = round(et - st, 1)
    print("Time Elapsed:", format_timespan(time_elapsed))
```

Generating random binned data to WOE-encode:

```
X_train_binned = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size = (20000, 1000))).astype(str)
X_test_binned = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size = (20000, 1000))).astype(str)

y_train = np.random.randint(0,2, size = (20000, ))
```

**1. Using `skorecard.WoeEncoder()`:**

```
tic()

woe = WoeEncoder()
woe.fit(X_train_binned, y_train) # fast
X_train_WOE_1 = woe.transform(X_train_binned) # very slow
X_test_WOE_1 = woe.transform(X_test_binned) # very slow

toc()
```

> ```
> Time Elapsed: 3 minutes and 26.1 seconds
> ```

**2. Using my own functions:**

```
def woe_mapping_1d(X_train_binned_col, y_train, epsilon = 0.0001):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'feat': X_train_binned_col, 'target': y_train}).reset_index(drop = True)
    df['non_target'] = np.where(df['target'] == 1, 0, 1)
    
    woe_table = df.groupby('feat', as_index = False).agg(target_count = ('target', 'sum'), 
                                                         non_target_count = ('non_target', 'sum'))
    woe_table['pct_of_target'] = (woe_table['target_count'] / df['target'].sum()) + epsilon
    woe_table['pct_of_non_target'] = (woe_table['non_target_count'] / df['non_target'].sum()) + epsilon
    woe_table['WOE'] = np.log(woe_table['pct_of_non_target'] / woe_table['pct_of_target'])

    mapping_dict = dict(zip(woe_table['feat'], woe_table['WOE']))
    return mapping_dict


def create_woe_mapping_dict(X_train_binned, y_train, epsilon = 0.0001):
    woe_mapping_dict = {}

    for var in X_train_binned.columns:
        woe_mapping_dict[var] = woe_mapping_1d(X_train_binned_col = X_train_binned[var], y_train = y_train, epsilon = epsilon)
        
    return woe_mapping_dict


def apply_woe_mappings(X_binned, woe_mapping_dict, woe_value_unknown = 0):
    X_WOE_list = []
    
    for var in X_binned.columns:
        X_WOE_var = X_binned[var].map(woe_mapping_dict[var]).fillna(woe_value_unknown)
        X_WOE_list.append(X_WOE_var)
    
    X_WOE_df = pd.concat(X_WOE_list, axis = 1)
    return X_WOE_df
```

It runs ~40 times faster and produces the same results:

```
tic()

woe_dict = create_woe_mapping_dict(X_train_binned, y_train)

X_train_WOE_2 = apply_woe_mappings(X_train_binned, woe_dict)
X_test_WOE_2 = apply_woe_mappings(X_test_binned, woe_dict) 

toc()

print(X_train_WOE_1.equals(X_train_WOE_2))
print(X_test_WOE_1.equals(X_test_WOE_2))
```

> ```
> Time Elapsed: 5.3 seconds
> True
> True
> ```

How can I make it faster?